# How does one confirm a Magento bug?

Tags: discussion

I've been using Stack for a while now. And recently I encountered two bugs (problems) on our own site after which I was directed to stackexchange ([bug 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105068/mage-cookies-clear-not-working) and [bug 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270918/magento-1-9-1-not-sorting-configurable-product-attributes-dropdown-by-position)). I was struck by the simplicity of these bugs after I reproduced them in the latest Magento version - and wondered:

- why have these bugs existed so long? (1 more than 1 year old)
- and how can/should I have found these earlier?
- and why is the community not leveraging this knowledge?

which brings me to **my question**: would it be possible to mark questions/answers as BUG - when they are clearly a bug? I can image that we give medior/senior stack members the right to confirm a bug (so not everyone can do it)?

And please before you answer. Do realize I ask this because I want to increase our community leverage to make Magento even better.

(even in this meta discussion I see the labels that I mean: marked as `BUG`)

Comment: Please don't use the [meta-tag:bug] tag for things like this. It is for bugs with the [magento.se] site (and this meta site), as you can see from its description.

Answer (score 3):

That is an easy to answer question.
Combination of low affected users, and big amount of reported Issues.

To explain this, in the earlier days there was a bug tracker, it had a lot lot reports, some of them only questions, some not reproducable, and every thing was reported multiple times.
In such a situation, you need to have the right contacts or at least a very heavy affecting lot of users issue to get someone to handle it. Most of the times not even a combination of both was enough. So Issues and solutions get forgetten.

Today we have stackexchange, stackexchange does not forgett, and it solves the issue of duplicates quite good. So its just natural, that we find bugs (again) which are there since ever.

Some of them may be handled by magento, but remember there M1 capacities are limited today. I for example forwarded the cookie bug to openMage-lts to get resolved in their lts fork of magento.

Oh, and to The question how to confirm a bug: by peer review out of the community

Comment: Thx! How do we mark them? Suppose one would want to compose a list of true positive bugs ... I see many reports but they are either confirmed or unconfirmed and more importantly not consistently tagged - would this be a by-task for a medior/senior user:: confirming and consistently tagging it as a bug?

Comment: It could be one, I think noone would object if someone starts to tag posts as "possible-core-bug" and "bug" in general, I for myself try to move them into an external entity like openmage-lts so others which are speciallized with magentos internal bugs can more easy find them and see whats already solves there

Comment: Cross posting them to the magento reddit and also twitter may also help